# Depending on an inputed number, extend the given string

Tags: c, string

If N is a positive number, extend given string S, for N places, using character C. Complete it using a function and in the main function check if the function works. Any value of N gives me "it doesn't work".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cat(char*,char,int);
int main()
{
    char S[20],C;
    int N;
    puts("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    puts("Enter string: ");
    gets(S);
    if (N<1)
        printf("it's unknown whether it works");
    else if(cat(S,C,N)==strlen(S)+N)
            printf("it works.");
    else
        printf("it doesn't work.");
}
int cat(char*S,char C,int N){
int i;
char T[20];
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    T[i]=C;
return strlen(strcat(S,T));
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line.

Comment: It's not the root cause of your main problem but `C` is used uninitialized. and `T` can easily be overflowed if `N` is greater than 20.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to initialize the `C` character variable:

   ```
   char C = 'C';
   ```
2. The `strcat` function concatenates the 2 string parameters & returns a string whose length is equal to the sum of the 2 strings' length. So you need to declare a new array whose size is `string1 + string2`'s length in the `cat` function that will hold the concatenation result. Then `return` its length.